# Airflow SSH operator getting failed post sftp operations

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

We are using a SSH operator and executing the scripts in the docker. However, this was to work successfully. Don't know now its not working. Basically our script at DAG level creates the environment in Task1, Tasks2 for the sftp, Task3 to capture these logs below. Wanna help.

```
[2023-03-29, 13:38:34 ] {ssh.py:441} INFO - Running command: docker logs --follow project-docker-execution-dev
[2023-03-29, 13:38:50 ] {ssh.py:473} INFO - ********************** Error in spftp connection ************************
Some FTP Error occured : 
[2023-03-29, 13:38:50 ] {ssh.py:473} INFO - Error: connect: getConnection: All configured authentication methods failed
    at SftpClient.fmtError (project1/node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/src/index.js:111:22)
    at SftpClient.connect (project1/node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/src/index.js:249:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_GENERIC_CLIENT',
  custom: true
}
```

Please review the error, the server is having the port is open at the machine level.

```
$lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
rpcbind     549      rpc    8u  IPv4   19616      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
rpcbind     549      rpc   11u  IPv6   19619      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
master     1125     root   13u  IPv4   23771      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:25 (LISTEN)
master     1125     root   14u  IPv6   23772      0t0  TCP [::1]:25 (LISTEN)
sshd       1187     root    3u  IPv4   25340      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1187     root    4u  IPv6   25342      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
nginx      1304     root    6u  IPv4   26681      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1304     root    7u  IPv6   26682      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1313    nginx    6u  IPv4   26681      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1313    nginx    7u  IPv6   26682      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1314    nginx    6u  IPv4   26681      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1314    nginx    7u  IPv6   26682      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
rte-senso  3529     root   46u  IPv4   36321      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9091 (LISTEN)
```